# How to get a flattened list from nested class List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a [question using these same examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838103/how-can-i-use-a-class-as-a-data-model-in-querying-xdocument) - this question is focused on a different issue.
Given the following classes:

```
   [XmlRoot]
   public class Family {

      [XmlElement]
      public List<Person> Person;
   }

   public class Person {

      [XmlAttribute("member")]
      public MemberType Member { get; set; }

      [XmlAttribute("id")]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public string Surname { get; set; }

      [XmlElement]
      public string Forename { get; set; }

      [XmlElement("Person")]
      public List<Person> People;
   }

   public enum MemberType {
      Father,
      Mother,
      Son,
      Daughter
   }
```

If `Family` has a method defined as such:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find (Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    //  how do I get SelectMany to flatten the list?
    foreach (var p in family.Person.SelectMany(p => p)) {
        if(predicate(p)) {
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to execute the predicate over a flattened list of `Person`. In the example above `SelectMany` is not flattening the list as I had hoped. The above actually won't compile because the inferred type cannot be determined.

How can I get the Family.Person collection to become one flattened list of Person?

Comment: If you have loops in your data structure you can this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141467/recursive-list-flattening/24747394#answer-24747394

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find(IEnumerable<Person> input, Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    return input.Select(p => 
        {
            var thisLevel = new List<Person>();
            if(predicate(p))
                thisLevel.Add(p);

            return thisLevel.Union(Find(p.People ?? new List<Person>(), predicate));
        }
    ).SelectMany(p => p);
}
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the recursive data structure, the question didn't make this point obvious enough :)

Comment: I recommend Concat over Union since there is no need to screen for cross-set duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, the easiest way to accomplish this is using a helper.

```
    private List<Person> FlattenTree(Person person)
    {
        var accumulator = new List<Person>();
        FlattenPersonHelper(person, accumulator);

        return accumulator;
    }


    private void FlattenPersonHelper(Person person, List<Person> accumulator)
    {
        accumulator.Add(person);

        foreach (var child in person.People)
        {
            FlattenPersonHelper(child, accumulator);
        }
        return;
    }
```

You can then run your predicate against this list:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find (Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    var familyRoot = new Person() { People = family.Person };
    return FlattenTree(familyRoot).Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! and Thanks! PS I use this pattern often enough that I've written a generic version as an extension method. Super useful.

Answer (score 4):

SelectMany only flattens one level of hierarchy:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> FindLevel2 (Func<Person, bool> predicate)
{
  return family.Person.SelectMany(p => p.People).Where(predicate);
}
```

---

You might actually want an arbitrary depth walk of the hierarchy.  That's best done by recursion (Untested).

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find(Func<Person, bool> predicate)
{
  foreach(Person p in family.Person)
  {
    IEnumerable<Person> result = FindFromPerson(p);
    foreach(Person x in result)
    {
      yield return x;
    }
  }
}

public IEnumerable<Person> FindFromPerson(Person p, Func<Person, bool> predicate)
{
  if predicate(p)
  {
    yield return p;
  }
  foreach(Person child in p.People)
  {
    IEnumerable<Person> childResults = FindFromPerson(child);
    foreach(Person x in childResults)
    {
      yield return x;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need both `SelectMany` and `yield return` - you need one or the other:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find (Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (var p in family.Person) {
        if(predicate(p)) {
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find (Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    return family.Person.Where(p => predicate(p)); // Can be written simply as Where(predicate)
}
```

Comment: *'p => predicate(p)'* can be reduced to just *'predicate'* - atm you're wrapping one *Func<Person, Bool>* with another.

Comment: @MattDavey I added a wrapper to remove the "magic" from the expression. I added a comment line to say that it can be simplified. It is just that looking at a `Where` clause without `=>` in it may be confusing to people with relatively little LINQ experience.

Comment: yeah I think that's a pertinent thing to do :)

Answer (score 2):

`family.Person` *already is* a flattened list; there's no need to call `SelectMany` on it.

```
foreach (var p in family.Person) {
    if(predicate(p)) {
        yield return p;
    }
}
```

Also, you can more simply do:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Find (Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
    return family.Person.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: notice that Person has a nested *List<Person>*. It is **not** a flattened list, it's a recursive data structure.

Comment: @Matt - I totally didn't see that  -  especially considering OP's original code of `family.Person.SelectMany(p => p)`  I'd edit to fix, but it looks like Petr already knocked it out of the park